# Office 365 Rest API Access to public folders

Tags: api, office365, outlook-restapi

How do I access public folders using the office 365 REST API (or the .net client api)?

I can quite happily work my through my folders but I can't figure out how to get a list of public folders (and access their contents).

As a plan B I can see the folders using EWS but I'd rather use the REST API.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The REST API doesn't support public folder access. EWS would be the way to go if you need PF access.

Comment: Here's information about public folder access with EWS. https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/jj945067(v=exchg.150).aspx

Comment: Thanks guys and nice to hear I didn't just miss something in the documentation.